# Amazon EC2 Tomcat does not work with my domain-issued SSL certificate

Tags: tomcat, ssl, amazon-ec2, dns, ssl-certificate

Ok, here's the scoop.

I obtained an SSL Certificate for my domain, let's call it www.mydomain.com from namecheap.

My website is hosted on a Tomcat7 webserver, which resides on an Amazon AWS EC2 linux instance with a public IP.  I installed my certificate on this EC2 server and configured tomcat to redirect all http requests to https.

When I try to access my website via URL, I get a warning from my browser saying that the connection is untrusted.  This makes sense since I'm trying to access the site via ip rather than the domain name (mydomain.com).

To remedy this, I tried to set up URL Redirection (URL Frame) on namecheap (where my domain is registered), but this didn't fix the problem.  Namecheap said I need to get a new certificate to secure my IP rather than the domain, but I wonder if there are any other options out there?

Specifically, can I...
  - utilize Amazon's DNS (Route53) instead of namecheap's DNS?
  - migrate my domain registration over to Amazon? (I have my e-mail hosted on namecheap and don't want to lose it)?
  - other options?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can I just use [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/set-hostname.html)?  If so, will I need to update my url redirection on namecheap?

Comment: Are you using a load balancer (ELB)?  Or is tomcat receiving the requests directly?  Did you install your cert in Tomcat? https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Point the A Record of your domain to the public IP EC2 gave you.Or better yet, grab an elastic IP, associate it to your instance, and point the A Record to that.

Comment: This did it.  I wished I hadn't wasted an hour of my life on support with namecheap.  Thanks!